# Php code wont work in browser with wamp after installing aptana

Tags: php, wamp, aptana

I have been working with the wamp stack for awhile now and I recently installed aptana to work on a project for one of my classes.  After installing aptana, I found that when I go to my old projects in wamp, anything that includes php code no longer displays.  When I go to the wamp error log I see this:

```
    [Tue May 06 16:46:05.875535 2014] [:error] [pid 2804:tid 1020] [client ::1:49913] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'includes/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.25-1/php/PEAR;C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.25-1/frameworks/smarty/libs') in C:\\Bitnami\\wampstack-5.4.25-1\\apache2\\htdocs\\AnimeOtaku\\index.php on line 5

    [Tue May 06 16:46:05.875535 2014] [:error] [pid 2804:tid 1020] [client ::1:49913] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sec_session_start() in C:\\Bitnami\\wampstack-5.4.25-1\\apache2\\htdocs\\AnimeOtaku\\index.php on line 7
```

This also applies to anything with which I am currently working on which means if I can't see what it is that I am doing, I am unable to work with it.

Comment: Have you checked your includes path? Is it correct? Is that where your includes actually live? You may need to edit your php.ini file...

Comment: Slightly retarded question but where might I edit that at?  And would would I need to edit it to?